# Defining functions recursively in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, lambda

I have a simple question about lambda functions. I want to do a loop, in which every iteration defines a new lambda function based on a lambda function from the previous iteration.

```
f = lambda x: x**2
j=0
J=2
while j<J:
    f2 = lambda x: 0.5*f(x)
    f = f2
    j+=1
```

I expect the result of f(3) to be 2.25 = 0.5*0.5*3**2. However, I get the following error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I thought lambda functions can be used flexibly like this. I suppose there is a known pythonic way of how to do this properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name `f` inside your lambda is looked up *at the time the lambda is called* - at which point it refers to the lambda itself, thus the infinite recursion.

The usual idiom for capturing a value at a particular moment in time is to make it a default parameter of the lambda, which gets evaluated at definition time:

```
    f2 = lambda x, f=f: 0.5*f(x)
```

Comment: Is there also a way to do this using `def` rather than `lambda`?

Comment: Sure, the same trick with default parameters works just as well for a regular function.  Keep in mind that lambdas do not add any actual new functionality to Python, they're just a shortcut for defining really simple functions.

Answer (score 3):

When a `lambda` function is created, it maintains a reference to the local environment so that it can look up variables within the `lambda` when it is called. You need to pass in your first `lambda` function as a parameter to the second one:

```
f = lambda x: x**2
j=0
J=2
while j<J:
    f2 = lambda x, f=f: 0.5*f(x)
    f = f2
    j+=1
```

Note that this is covered in the [Python docs FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result).

Comment: Because the answers are exactly the same, I accepted the first one. Thank you

Comment: Is there also a way to do this using `def` rather than `lambda`?