# Python recursive function definition storage issue

Tags: python, recursion, math, lambda

I am trying to get a list of functions defined recursively by storing each step of a math serie:
`x^0+x^1+x^2+x^3+...` → `f0(x)=1, f1(x)=1+x, f2(x)=1+x+x², f3(x)=1+x+x²+x³, ...`

I coded this in python:

```py
n = 3
devs = [lambda x: 1]
for k in range(n):
    devs.append(lambda x, f=devs[k]: f(x) + x**(k+1))
print(devs[-1](4))  # x=4
```

I learned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42357834/defining-functions-recursively-in-python) that you need to pass the previous function as default argument in order to solve the *maximum recursion depth* error, but this outputs `193`.
I think it has to do with the `k` in the default parameter. It seems to calculate: `1+4^3+4^3+4^3=193`, or more accurately `1+n*x^n` instead of `x^0+x^1+...+x^n`

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the same question you linked has the answer to your problem. Because the k inside the function is evaluated only outside the loop, it will have the last value from the loop. You can check [the documention](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result) for how it works in depth.
The correct code is

```
n = 4
devs = [lambda x: 1]
for k in range(n):
    devs.append(lambda x, f=devs[k], j=k: f(x) + x**(j+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner just for fun!

```py
n=10
devs = (lambda f:[f] + [f := (lambda x, a=k, g=f: g(x) + x**(a+1)) for k in range(n)])(lambda x:1)
```